Identifying required surfaces to add shadows in three js
I'm learning three js recently and I'm trying to mimic the scene which is present in below link by downloading the model
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/ccity-building-set-1-a2d5c7bfcc2148fb8994864c43dfcc97
I've downloaded gltf model and tried to add shadows to all the children in the scene
and it came like this. It's not looking good and all the road surfaces also have shadows

So I've checked the details in gltf scene. and I've applied shadows only to surfaces which is not ConcreteSurfaces. Now it looks like this. Still surfaces on buildings are getting shadows and some of the buildings shadows are missing

Below is my code which I'm using.
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const modelUrl = new URL('./assets/ground/scene.gltf', import.meta.url);
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        // renderer.setClearColor(0xA3A3A3);
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;

        refContainer.current && refContainer.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        camera.position.set(100, 100, -100);

        // camera.updateMatrix();
        orbit.update();


        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFBCEB1, 10000 );
        spotLight.position.set( -500, 200, 100 );
        spotLight.angle = 0.4;
        spotLight.penumbra = 0.05;
        spotLight.decay = 1;
        spotLight.distance = 2000;

        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add( spotLight );

        spotLight.target.position.set( 3, 0, - 3 );
        scene.add( spotLight.target );
        const helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper( spotLight, 5 );
        scene.add( helper );


        const assetLoader = new GLTFLoader();


        assetLoader.load(modelUrl.href, function(gltf) {
            const model = gltf.scene;
            model.scale.set(0.01,0.01,0.01);
            model.position.z = 100
            model.position.x = 100
            model.traverse( function( child ) { 

                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    console.log(child)
                    var childName = child.name
                    if(!childName.includes('ConcreteBlock')) {
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                    }
                    
            
                }
            
            } );
            scene.add(model);
            
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });

        
        function animate() {
            // requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
        animate();

How to identify the surfaces which needs shadows so that the scene looks like in the above link??? Am i doing it in right way??

Change
 if ( child.isMesh ) {
    console.log(child)
    var childName = child.name
    if(!childName.includes('ConcreteBlock')) {
      child.castShadow = true;
      child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  }

to
  if ( child.isMesh ) {
    meshes.push(child)
    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;
  }

Because if(!childName.includes('ConcreteBlock')) {...} is excluding the ground plane.
To identify all meshes with a mouseover event add this:
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove(event) {
  // Calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates (-1 to +1)
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  // Update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  // Check for intersections
  meshes.forEach((mesh, index) => {
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        // Mouse is over the mesh
        console.log(mesh.name)
    } 
  })
}

Hope this helps, have fun.
